# Strange result for determinants

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have a matrix $X=\begin{bmatrix}3 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & 3 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$.

I want to get the determinant of $\lambda \mathbf{I}-X$ (to find an eigenvalue), which is $$\det\begin{bmatrix}\lambda-3 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & \lambda-3 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & \lambda-3
\end{bmatrix}=(\lambda-3)^3-1-1-3(\lambda-3)$$

However, my calculations show that the determinant should just be $(\lambda-3)^3$ and not $(\lambda-3)^3-1-1-3(\lambda-3)=(\lambda-3)^2-3\lambda-11$. I substituted for various values of $\lambda$ to check the determinant.

This is a very strange result as I have used the "crossing" method to find the determinant.

I have two questions:

1. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong in calculating the determinant?
2. Is it better to perform Gauss-Jordan elimination before calculating the determinant?

Comment: The det is $16$. Are you trying to calculate eigenvalues?

Comment: Shouldn't the $-1$ entries in the second matrix be positive?

Comment: Also, by observation $\lambda = 4$ should be an eigenvalue of multiplicity at least $2$.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to calculate eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks Theo Bendit, I think that is the careless error. The $-1$ entries in the second matrix are positive.

Comment: I think you have problem in calculating determinant of a matrix!

Comment: $$\det\begin{bmatrix}\lambda-3 & 1 & 1\\
1 & \lambda-3 & 1\\
1 & 1 & \lambda-3
\end{bmatrix} \neq (\lambda-3)^3-1-1-3(\lambda-3)$$

Comment: GhD, you're right. It should either be $3-\lambda$ or multiplying the $-1$ with the $1$s. I believe this is the careless error that I overlooked.

Comment: No. there is no difference between $\lambda-3$ and $3-\lambda$ you always got same eigenvalues by calculating determinant of $\lambda \mathbf{I}-X$ or determinant of $X-\lambda \mathbf{I}$

Comment: As in, I calculated $\lambda\mathbf{I} - X$ wrongly.

Comment: You calculated determinant of $\lambda \mathbf{I}-X$ wrongly. Calculate determinant of it again now.

Comment: The correct determinant would therefore be: $$\det\begin{bmatrix}\lambda-3 & 1 & 1\\
1 & \lambda-3 & 1\\
1 & 1 & \lambda-3
\end{bmatrix}=(\lambda-3)^{3}+11-3\lambda$$

Comment: no it is $(\lambda-3)^3+8-2\lambda$

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda \mathbf{I}-X$ is equal to:$$ \begin{bmatrix}\lambda-3 & 1 & 1\\
1 & \lambda-3 & 1\\
1 & 1 & \lambda-3
\end{bmatrix} $$

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean eigenvalues, therefore you need to do the following: replace $\lambda-3$ by $3-\lambda$ or replace all $-1$ by $1$. You will find $\lambda = 4$ twice and $\lambda = 1$.